# css columns and scroll transitions

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, multiple-columns

I am displaying a ebook paginated using CSS columns.
I am looking for a way to scroll pages (ie : to scroll horizontaly) using a page flip effect.

Do you know if this is achievable and if yes, what do I have to do?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: These might be a little helpful but they dont actually fully 'turn the page'

Comment: Which ones are you talking about?

Comment: oh sorry, link didnt work: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-page-peel-plugins/

Comment: thanks. However it does not help with my problem.